# How to docker stack on workers without internet connection

Tags: docker, docker-stack

I'm trying to use `docker-stack` in some machines that only the manager of them can have internet connection. The docker-stack file looks like follows:

```yaml
version: '3.7'

networks:
  monitor-net:

services:
  service:
    image: aaa/bbb
    networks:
      - monitor-net
    deploy:
      mode: global
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
```

The problem I faced is that `docker stack` will pull the image, however my workers cannot connect to docker server, and it is impossible to pull it.

I tried to use `docker save` and `docker load` to transfer images which is downloaded by my manager node, however in `docker stack ps` it still reports `No such image: aaa/bbb:latest@sha256:xxxxxxx`.

I checked the digests of images and found with `docker load`, the digest of the image is changed to `<none>` so the loaded image is not recognized. Is there any way to transfer images to workers with their digests unchanged, or force `docker stack` to use the image without checking its digest?

Comment: you could deploy a private registry somewhere on the lan.

Comment: @the-fool Thank you fo your advice, I've not tried to deploy a registry before. I'll try it to see if it works.